# Apps using these permissions in an APK (android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS ) are required to have a *privacy policy* set

Tags: android-studio, apk, privacy-policy

Error: **android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a *privacy policy* set**.

How to fix it or take it of from my app at all ?
thanks *:)*

Comment: hi there, yes Google has recently started to enforce these requirements. You can either remove that permission (which likely will cripple your app's purpose), or add a privacy policy that describes your data processing accurately (in Arabic?). I'll make a few suggestions for you to follow in an actual answer.

Answer (score 3):

`GET_ACCOUNTS` [is a sensitive permission](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/personal-sensitive/) that requires a disclosure why and how are you using that data.

You can fix this by:

- Remove the sensitive permission (ie. do not use `GET_ACCOUNTS`)
- Or add a Privacy Policy to your Android app:

  1. Log into your Google Play Developer Console.
  2. Select "All Applications" and then select your application
  3. Click "Store Listing"
  4. Enter the public URL of your Privacy Policy at the "Privacy Policy field":

  [image: Privacy Policy field in Google Play Store by TermsFeed.com]

Note that Google Play Store won't host the policy for you. You need to have a public web page to host your Privacy Policy.

Answer (score 1):

Google has quite recently started enforcing these [so called sensitive permissions](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/#sensitive), so that's why you're seeing this error [- which can be fixed by providing a privacy policy](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/) (links to posts I've authored for this purpose).

The privacy policy can be added by accessing Google's Developer Console, but it's probably more important for you to understand how that privacy policy should be created. Here are some great guidelines by both a US authority (California) and European guidelines:

**A) Attorney General’s office in California**

```
The types or categories of personally identifiable data collected by the app.
The uses and retention period for each type or category of personally identifiable data.
Whether your app, or a third party, collects payment information for in-app purchases.
The categories of third parties with whom the app may share personally identifiable data. Such third parties include advertising networks and analytics providers. Provide a link to third parties’ privacy policy statements, where available.
The choices a user has regarding the collection, use, and sharing of user information, with instructions on how to exercise those choices.
The process for a user to review and request corrections to his or her personally identifiable information maintained by the app, if available.
A means for users to contact the app developer with questions or concerns.
The effective date of the privacy policy and the process for notifying users of material changes to it.
```

**B) European style (from a guide for mobile apps)**

Now, European style privacy policies are a lot more stringent in nature, and will continue to be more stringent with content under GDPR in 2018.

I’m pasting a minimal framework here from the Opinion 02/2013 on apps on smart devices.

If processing personal data the relevant data controller must inform potential users at the minimum about:

```
who they are (identity and contact detail),
the precise categories of personal data the app developer will collect and process,
why (for what precise purposes),
whether data will be disclosed to third parties
how users may exercise their rights, in terms of withdrawal of consent and deletion of data).
```

Of course that means that users must be informed properly about their rights of access, rectification, erasure and their right to object to data processing. Under GDPR, a regulation coming into full force next year (2018), things will complicate a lot in terms of disclosure.

*You'll know best what your requirements are. If writing something from scratch isn't your thing, I work on the topic of privacy daily and help create tools that help accomplish online compliance topics. You can find these [tools here at iubenda](https://www.iubenda.com/mobile). In complicated cases I'd also suggest to consult with a specialised lawyer.*

Answer (score 0):

> Adding Privacy Policy  ---> Please refer this link
>   [Click Here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?visit_id=1-636181561830097288-1046519841&rd=1#privacy)