# Uploading app on playstore but the response is permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA)

Tags: android

Uploading app on playstore but it gives me the error below:

```
 Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA)
```

My permissions on androidmanifest are as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

What would be the problem here

Answer (score 3):

Enter your privacy policy url into playstore, see here [Apps using these permissions in an APK (android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS ) are required to have a *privacy policy* set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138750/apps-using-these-permissions-in-an-apk-android-permission-get-accounts-are-re)

Also consider, one of the library that you are using can use the camera permission or that error might be buggy, but for gps permission you still need to add privacy policy url.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to go to Google play console and input the policy url for the app.